# Explanation of AUTOSAR BswMLinScheduleIndication container content

Tags: autosar

I am new to AUTOSAR and I am quite puzzled by the content of the BswMLinScheduleIndication configuration container. The issue is that this container includes not only a reference to LIN channel handle, but also a reference to LIN schedule table handle. I don't understand that since this container corresponds to mode request source of BswM_LinSM_CurrentSchedule() function. Description of the function states "Function called by LinSM to indicate the currently active schedule table for a specific LIN channel.", so naturally i conclude that currently active schedule table handle is the mode value, but in this case reference to LIN schedule table handle must belong to BswMModeValue container, isn't it? If LIN schedule table handle is not mode value, than what is?
Unfortunately AUTOSAR_EXP_ModeManagementGuide doesn't cover LIN issues.

Thank you in advance for your time and attention. Sorry for my bad english. I understand that my question can be mishaped, please forgive for that, since sometimes it's difficult for newbie event to formulate a right one.

Answer (score 1):

Check the LinSM and the LinIf SWS, which describe the change of the Schedule Tables of a LIN Master (and only the LIN Master). The LinIf switches between a `RUN_CONTINOUS` and `RUN_ONCE` schedule table.

Why LinIf needs schedule tables I can not tell. I never had a usage for LIN at work yet. Hope it still helps.